# Symlink, Am I Missing Something?

Tags: indexing, directory, symlink, public

I'm trying to symlink my `public` folder with a `index.php` file in it to the `httpdocs` folder where the public folder is also placed.

When I try and Symlink the public folder I get an error alerting me that the `public` folder name is already taken. I've also tried Symlinking the `index.php` file itself which worked but broke the functionality of the site.

Here is the command I'm using when Symlinking the `public` folder.

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs
```

Here is the command I used when Symlinking the `index.php` file.

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public/index.php /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs
```

tldr: I want to use the `index.php` in the public folder as the `index.php` file when a user visits my site without having to use `mysite.co.uk/public/index.php`. The `index.php` file has to remain in the `public` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work! I used a soft symlink on `public/index.php` in the `httpdocs` folder to make a `index.php` file also in the `httpdocs` folder.

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public/index.php /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/
```

I then added a `.htaccess` file to the `httpdocs` folder with the following...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you to @Attila for sticking with me and helping out!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to access `index.php` from `httpdocs/public`, and that folder already  exists (as the error in the first case informs).  You can link the file to that (exisitng) folder:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public/index.php
```

Note that you need to specify the file itlsef that you want to link

Comment: Yes the file I'm wanting to use as the "homepage" is already in the public folder `httpdocs/public/index.php`. To access this now I would have to visit `mysite.co.uk/public/index.php` but I want to just visit `mysite.co.uk` and get the same result, will this solution work for me?

Comment: If I was to put the source in a different place I'd have the same problem, it would jus create a `/public` folder/symlink in my `httpdocs`

Comment: It needs to be within the /mysite.co.uk/ folder.

Comment: See last update (I hope I got it right this time :)).  You need to specify the file name in both cases and the first path is the [one created](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln)

Comment: Then use: `ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/index.php ...`

Comment: Ypu can do both `ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/index.php ...` and `ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php ...`

Comment: I've managed to set it up but now I'm getting this error on my webpage `Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/app/public/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs:/tmp) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Is (/home/vhosts/ the "real" path to the file?  It seems the symbolic link is resolved before the file is accessed: 1) you need to add the proper directory to the allowed paths or 2) use hard link instead of the symbolic link (do not set `-s` for `ln`)

Comment: What is the difference between hard link and no -s?

Comment: Soft link is a "reference" to the real file: the file system needs to follow the reference to get to the real file.  Hard links are the [same file](http://justlikeamagic.com/2010/04/06/hard-links-vs-soft-links/): think of physically copying the file, but if you make changes to one, the other will change as well.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution** (if *all* files are required in `…/public` and `…/httpdocs`.

- move your data from `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public` to `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs`
- symlink `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs` to `…/public`

Command: `ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public`

Cons:

- infinite recursion, for instance `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/public/public/public/public/`

---

It is not possible to `symlink` to an existing file/directory. If it would be possible, you would break your tree structure. In fact you are trying to link a directory to its parent. How should your system resolve overwritten paths?

Example:

You have a file /a/b/c and it would be possible to do the following:

`ln -s /a/b /a`

How should the system resolve the now not reachable file `/a/b/c`?

Move your data into the desired directory instead of trying to break your file tree.

It is possible to mount data to existing directories (original data will be unreachable until unmount), but this would not help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If you read the comments in the other answer I tried this and got an error...

Comment: It works but you just did not explain what you are doing. For instance /home is not /var and if you do not correctly set up your PHP configuration (open_basedir *hint*), we are not able to help you.